# Automatic hyperlinks within document?

Tags: links

I'm new to TeX (and I'm still trying to get my hear around it.)

I was wondering is there a package that automatically creates links within the document I am writing - like hyperlinking from the table of contents to the specific sections, or citations to the bibliographic data?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package will automatically generate hyperlinks for the table of contents and citations. Be sure to add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your document preamble *after* loading any other packages, since `hyperref` makes some serious changes to the internals of LaTeX- there are some exceptions, which are detailed in [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

An example document might look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% add any other packages here.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{My Document}
\author{A. U. Thor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{A Section}
This section will automatically be added to the table of contents, as normal. The table of
contents entry for this section will automatically hyperlink to it. Also, a PDF bookmark
will be added.

\section{Another Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: If, like me, you find the boxes that hyperlink puts around its links to be impossibly ugly then you can instead make the text of the links an arbitrary color in the fashion of the following example: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=yellow,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=cyan]{hyperref}`